# What is the argument AGAINST the position that only Paul's writings are applicable to the church today?

Tags: biblical-basis, paul-apostle, dispensationalism, hyperdispensationalism

In mid-Acts dispensationalism (a form of [hyperdispensationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperdispensationalism)), it is taught that only Paul's writings (from Romans to Philemon) are applicable to the church today and that the other parts of the Bible are informational only.

What is the logical and biblical argument against this position?  I'm interested in an argument that emphasizes Paul's writings themselves.

Comment: Seriously? There are Christians who think that the teachings of Jesus are 'for information only'?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes... It seems pretty untenable.  My dad just called me and told me someone in his church had gotten into this.  That's what has prompted this question and my own personal research.  Oddly enough the gospel of John was likely written after the death of Paul, but somehow is supposed to be only for Jewish prior to the conversion of Paul.

Comment: Surely Paul's many quotes of and allusions to the OT show that there good to be found in reading the OT. He uses the OT and shows us how it is applicable today, such as Rom. 1:17.

Comment: I to listen arguments that Jesus in his gospels and many other arguments of the other writers of the New testiment, focus on the fact that Christ was only speaking to the Jews.  This is a method used to support that the teachings of Christ himself which would otherwise refute the false doctrine of the "Rapture", "in context", Actually support it because Christ was mot speaking to the Church but only to Jews. The other ecclesial body lead astray, not knowing any differently, buy into it hook line and sinker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was actually the [Marcionite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcionism) position - namely that the Gospel of "grace" as revealed by Paul, superceded everything else.

Marcion's Canon consisted of 10 books - 9 of which were Pauline Epistles and the remaining of which was the [Euangelion](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/marcion.html), a "Gospel" of sorts that rejected the bodily incarnation of Christ and understood the Hebrew Bible to be the result of the demiurge - an evil counterpart to the God who was strictly one of grace.  Indeed, Marcion is often considered one of the first heretics - precisely for believing that *only* Paul's words were inspired.  (On the bright side, it was his canon that eventually led the church to form a consensus on what the full canon was.)

That early Gnostic tendencies are being rediscovered by moderns who have innovative views of Scripture is not overly remarkable.

The answer, of course, is that Paul himself rejected the later Marcionite position. His warnings against false teachers who taught things other than what Jesus and the Dsiciples did.  He writes in 2 Thessalonians:

> But we ought always to thank God for you, brothers and sisters loved by the Lord, because God chose you as first fruits to be saved through the sanctifying work of the Spirit and through belief in the truth. 14 He called you to this through our gospel, that you might share in the glory of our Lord Jesus Christ.
>
> 15 So then, brothers and sisters, stand firm and hold fast to the teachings[c] we passed on to you, whether by word of mouth or by letter.

Paul's message shows God's grace, but reminds us as well that God's justice is also a part of his nature.  Indeed, the role of the law is not to be discounted. He writes in Galatians 3:24

> So then, the law was our guardian until Christ came, in order that we might be justified by faith.

That isn't a rejection of the law at all.  Grace may be greater than Law, but law is still there!

Comment: Great information and answer. Thank you for explaining about the Marcionite belief.

Answer (score 5):

> **All Scripture is inspired by God and profitable** for teaching, for
>   reproof, for correction, for training in righteousness; so that the
>   man of God may be adequate, equipped for every good work.
>
> 2 Timothy 3:16-17

Not just a portion, but ALL Scripture is profitable so that the man of God may be equipped for every good work.

> Bear in mind that our Lord’s patience means salvation, just as **our
>   dear brother Paul also wrote you** with the wisdom that God gave him.
>   He writes the same way in all his letters, speaking in them of these
>   matters. His letters contain some things that are **hard to
>   understand**, **which ignorant and unstable people distort**, **as
>   they do the other Scriptures**, to their own destruction.
>
> 2 Peter 3:15-16

People even in the early church had started to take Paul's writings and twist it for their own use. Today the same is being done, and because some of Paul's writings are hard to understand, we must be careful and use the Bible as a whole so that we may know the message that Paul is trying to convey.

EDIT: In order to make this answer complete I've been researching on this subject and reading the word. I read through 2 Peter and it is an amazing aid in this subject. Nevertheless, if someone only believes in the writings of Paul, I must find the answer in the writings of Paul. I will continue the research and post my findings as soon as I have an answer.

Comment: The OT is part of scripture, and 'profitable', but most Christians would consider that the laws contained therein are not applicable to the church today (we eat pork and don't sacrifice animals). What is needed is an argument that The Gospels don't fall into the same category.

Comment: Well we don't sacrifice animals because they were a foreshadowing and a symbol of the Ultimate Sacrifice, the Lamb of God, Jesus Christ.  Also you're right in saying 'most Christians' meaning not all. Some Christians do not eat pork because God said it would be an abomination to do so. Also this law was given to all mankind, not just to the Jews. As were the 10 Commandments. This is why it is dangerous to take something that Paul said out of context, because some people distort what he said to be able to do what they wish, instead of what God wishes.

Comment: By the way @DJClayworth, I just reread my comment and the last part sounded like a personal attack. It is not, I merely stated what Peter said in his second epistle. If it is offensive let me know and I will edit, but I just wanted to let you know it was not written with this intention.

Comment: You miss my point. There is good reason - from scripture and the teachings of Jesus - to say that the OT rules are no longer applicable to Christians today. Your answer doesn't explain why that might (or might not) also apply to the Gospels, which is what the question is about.

Comment: I see. I will edit it. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @DJClayworth I do not agree that there is any good reason to say old testament laws are not applicable to Christians today. The ten commandments hold fast forever. It is wrong today to kill, to steal, to commit adultery, to break Sabbath etc... Only the sacrificial laws and civil laws are not applicable anymore.